# How do I handle the special character ‘/’ in rasa?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

For example, the following sentence: “hi good afternoon how are you doing”. The intent of this joke is ‘greet’. When I request the API of ‘model / parse’, it will return the correct intent and entity. But when I add the special character ‘/’ in front of this sentence, such as: “/ hi good afternoon how are you doing”, the intention returned by ‘model / parse’ is ‘/ hi good afternoon how are you doing’ instead of ‘greet’. I read the source code of rasa, as follows: 
[image]

How do I deal with the special character ‘/’ to take into account the RegexInterpreter of the source code and I cite this example？ It is best to solve it without modifying the source code. Please help me, thanks.

**answer to:**

I want to implement the following three functions at the same time:

1. When message.text = '/ greet {"people": "tom"}':

The actual result returned by ‘model / parse’ is as follows:

```
 {
        "text": "/ greet {\" people \ ": \" tom \ "}",
        "intent": {
            "name": "greet",
            "confidence": 1.0
        },
        "intent_ranking": [
            {
                "name": "greet",
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        "entities": [
            {
                "entity": "people",
                "start": 6,
                "end": 22,
                "value": "tom"
            }
        ]
    }
```

2, when message.text = 'Hi Tom, good afternoon'

The actual result returned by ‘model / parse’ is as follows:

```
{
    "text": "Hi Tom, good afternoon",
    "intent": {
        "name": "greet",
        "confidence": 0.923
    },
    "intent_ranking": [
        {
            "name": "greet",
            "confidence": 0.923
        }
    ],
    "entities": [
        {
            "entity": "people",
            "start": 2,
            "end": 5,
            "value": "tom",
            "confidence": 0.8433478958,
            "extractor": "CRFEntityExtractor"
        }
    ]
}
```

3, when message.text = '/ Hi Tom, good afternoon'

The actual result returned by ‘model / parse’ is as follows (this is not what I want):

```
{
    "text": "/ Hi Tom, good afternoon",
    "intent": {
        "name": "Hi Tom, good afternoon",
        "confidence": 1.0
    },
    "intent_ranking": [
        {
            "name": "Hi Tom, good afternoon",
            "confidence": 1.0
        }
    ],
    "entities": []
}
```

But the result I expect is as follows:

```
{
    "text": "Hi Tom, good afternoon",
    "intent": {
        "name": "greet",
        "confidence": 0.923
    },
    "intent_ranking": [
        {
            "name": "greet",
            "confidence": 0.923
        }
    ],
    "entities": [
        {
            "entity": "people",
            "start": 2,
            "end": 5,
            "value": "tom",
            "confidence": 0.8433478958,
            "extractor": "CRFEntityExtractor"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the third and second difference is that the third message.text only adds '/' at the beginning

Therefore, is there a method that can solve this problem well, and can satisfy the above three situations at the same time?

Comment: Do you want to make it impossible for users to directly trigger an intent using `/`? this will only happen when `/` is at the beginning of a user message, not if it's later in the message.

Comment: Hi,Melinda.Since the content of the reply is too long, I added the reply content to the original question, you can start from 'answer to'

Answer (score 0):

The presence of `/` at the beginning of a user message is the set way to trigger an intent directly. From the example you've given, it doesn't look like something that would occur frequently (if at all) in a real user situation. That said, if you do want to be sure that only actual intents can be triggered with the `/`, you could create a [custom component](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/custom-nlu-components/) which strips off any leading `/` if it is not followed by an intent already in your training data.

However, before going to that effort, I'd recommend checking how often this is actually happening.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that it is not feasible to use Custom NLU Components. Because rasa.core.processor._parse_message is executed before calling NLU Components.